# What is the significance of the Blasto 6 Movie Poster?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-2

On the citadel, between the priority missions, I've noticed that there is a movie poster in the apartments area of the commons which can be activated.  None of the other posters give me this option, and this one spits out dialogue.

It didn't trigger a journal entry or anything else that I can tell, is there any significance to it at all?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's an Easter Egg of sorts. [Blasto the Jellyfish](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Entertainment#Blasto_the_Jellyfish_Stings) is a popular action hero in the Mass Effect universe. He's the first Hanar SPECTRE, and was featured in a commercial in **Mass Effect 2**, which makes extensive use of lines from *Dirty Harry*:

The origin of Blasto is a joke by one of the ME Writers on the Bioware forums:

> Blasto is a reference to a joke made by writer Patrick Weekes on the official Mass Effect forums. When posting in a thread titled 'Your ideal ME2 squad', he included "Blasto the zany multi-pistol-wielding hanar gunslinger with a dark past, a heart of platinum, and the tendency to shout, "Enkindle THIS!" in combat." Blasto quickly became popular among fans, with Weekes noting "I am never going to live that joke down."

In **Mass Effect 3**, Blasto returns in *Blasto 6: Partners in Crime*, which, if you interact with the billboard repeatedly, you'll be able to hear about 10 minutes of dialog from. Dialog which is suspiciously similar to *Lethal Weapon*.

Other dialog around the Citadel will inform you that *Blasto 6* has broken box office records (set by *Blasto 5*, natch), and that it is a very hotly anticipated release.

For my money though, I'd rather see [Elcor Hamlet](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uIfx32iAjzU)

Comment: Almost every line in Blasto 6 is a Lethal Weapon reference. Awesome, because I love the Lethal Weapon franchise.

Answer (score 4):

It's purpose is to be there to be hilarious, and you can listen to the full recording in the following video:

But yes, it's just an easter egg relating back to a joke by writer Patrick Weekes about his idea for an ideal Mass Effect squad member - Blasto, the first Hanar Spectre.

Answer (score 1):

It's purely for "aesthetics" like an easter egg or the fish tank.